# Can I disable internet access permission for my ios application?

Tags: ios, permissions

We have developed a standalone IOS application and I need to disable the internet access permission for the application permanently.

Is there a way I can disable the internet access permission like [the way I can do with Android apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)?

Comment: A good way to begin is [from the source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17810298#17810298).

Comment: If you don't need internet access in your app then why do u want to disable it if you won't use it?

Comment: @Vaachar , this is been developed as an enterprise app , and the security review found that the app is capable of accessing internet . We have to get rid of this to continue with the deployment

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. Apps themselves don't "magically" access internet, you need code behind hit to let it do that. Ask your security review team for clarification.

Comment: it is a fun situation here xD

Answer (score 1):

There is no Internet access permission for apps in iOS - applications are always allowed to use network connectivity if it is available.  As commenters have said, this shouldn't be a security issue if you have written then app yourself, because you know what the app does and if you don't want it to access the Internet, then don't write code to access the Internet.

You need to ask your security review for clarification.  If your app includes a `UIWebView` it may be that the web view allows browsing to arbitrary web sites - in which case you need to ensure that your delegate method for the web view blocks attempts to load unauthorised URLs

Comment: Well, I currently have a similar case right now. You can write an app yourself, but still use third-party apps which you don't necessarily trust 100%. I would like to prevent internet access entirely in my app (or, at least, severely restrict it to, say, certain addresses). If what you say is true, I have no easy means to do that.

Comment: Do you mean third-party frameworks? If you don't trust them, don't use them.

Comment: In my case, I am using React Native. It uses 100's if not 1000's of NPM modules. It would indeed be nice to trust them all, but how can you? That's why my feeling is if you are using JavaScript and NPM, you must find a way to sandbox your application, to absolutely guard agains unauthorized data leaking.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the wrong tool then. If your project requires a higher level of trust than you are prepared to give to react native then you should be coding in Swift or Objective C. Using open source is a trade-off between your time and the risk associated with someone else's code (both security and support risks). You need to balance that trade off according to your requirements. Regardless, there is no access to packet filtering on iOS.

Comment: That's really too bad. They have many other permissions so nicely adjustable. Network access is so fundamental - I realize that most apps want it, but when you don't, you don't!